# How to add my own typescript classes in Electron project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm creating a hello world project in Electron and found out I can use Typescript for the Main process, https://electronjs.org/blog/typescript.

It says to use Typescript change the file extension from index.js to index.ts and then update the package.json to point to the new script:

```
{
  "name": "electrontypescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Typescript and Electron",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

It works but when I went to add my own class it throws errors.

Top of index.ts:

```
const { TypeHouse } = require ("./TypeHouse");
```

TypeHouse.ts:

```
function test() {

}

export class Cat {

}

export class TypeHouse {
   public status: String = "ready";
   private _output: String = "";
   readonly startTime = Date.now();
   private running: Boolean = false;

   constructor(private _message: String, private _prompt: String) {
       this.setStatus(_message);
   }

   async execute(): Promise<void> {
       try {
           //await CommandExecutor.execute(this);
       } catch (exception) {
           this.handleError(exception);
       } finally {
           //this.emit("end");
       }
   }

   handleError(message: TypeHouse | string): void {
       this.setStatus("Status.Failed");
       if (message) {
          // 
       }
   }

   isRunning(): boolean {
       return this.running !== false;
   }

   public setStatus(value: String) {
       this._output = value;
   }
}

module.exports = {TypeHouse, Cat};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Electron",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

Error message:

> App threw an error during load Error: Cannot find module './TypeHouse'
>   Require stack:
>   - /Users/projects/ElectronApp/index.ts
>   - /Users/projects/ElectronApp/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js

I'm using Visual Studio Code if it matters (it throws the error in the console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron is providing type declarations not the ability to run TypeScript directly. We still need to transpile TypeScript to JavaScript before running it.

1. Keep your `main` pointing at `index.js`.
2. Transpile your TypeScript.
3. Then call `npm start`.

In step (2) we will transpile the index.ts and TypeHouse.ts files into JavaScript. Here is how to get started transpiling TypeScript to Javascript. From your project directory run these these commands:

```
npm install -g typescript
tsc --init        // create a tsconfig.json file with reasonable default values
tsc               // transpile your TypeScript to JavaScript
npm start         // run the output index.js file
```

> Hmm... where do you put the npm run build? Do I replace the value in the start property? I've updated the post with package.json

```
{
  "name": "electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Electron",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",             <--------------------------
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

From there you can do `npm run build` from the command line, which will be the equivalent of doing `./node_modules/.bin/tsc`.

Comment: Thank you! If I use `-g` in `npm install -g typescript` that will install typescript globally so in my next project I don't have to call that command?

Comment: It looks like if I use the -g flag it returns an error: 
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

Comment: I think that's happening because I've been installing electron into the local project folder. I removed the -g option and installed it into my project using `npm install --save-dev typescript`. OK so now `tsc` is not in the path. _bash: tsc: command not found_. Calling it with `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc`

Comment: Ah forgot `-g` requires `sudo`.

Comment: Yes. `-g` is a global install. What I tend to do is `npm install typescript --save-dev` and then to add an `npm run build` script to package.json.

Comment: Hmm... where do you put the `npm run build`? Do I replace the value in the `start` property? I've updated the post with `package.json`.

Comment: I added an update to the answer that includes how to add an `npm run build` script.