# Fix "Continue without scanning the task output" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've created a task to run typescript and I go to Terminal > Run Task and select my Build Typescript task.

It then shows the message:

> Continue without scanning the task output

[image]

I've read the linked page but couldn't find anything. How do I get rid of this message?

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Typescript",
            "command": "tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Never scan the task output"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey No. I don't want to choose that without knowing what it means.

Comment: It scans the output of the task command for problems. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want it to list problems before compile.

Comment: So, the link I provided tells you what "scanning the task output" means. I'm not sure why you're creating a custom task for `tsc`, since VSCode will automatically build TypeScript files as you go: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript. Please [edit] your question to be a bit more clear on what the end result of your task should be, and whether scanning the task output is something you want to happen or not.

Comment: According to this answer I need to call tsc manually, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498489/how-to-add-my-own-typescript-classes-in-electron-project

Comment: I've read the link you provided, https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers but I don't know what to do that information.

Comment: It's important to include as much information about your environment as you can to questions. I don't know how Electron works, so I can't give further advice, but you shouldn't need to create a VSCode task to support TypeScript; you should be able to add a tsconfig.json to your project.

Comment: Peter has provided the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/58782412/44815

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you just want that message to not appear for this specific task, then add this to your task:

```
"problemMatcher": []
```

If you want your output to be scanned choose or make a problem matcher. You can read more about it in this section of the vs code docs:

[Processing task output with problem matchers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers)

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.json` you can also set `"task.problemMatchers.neverPrompt": true`. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg5GvgLzmzg) has a good explanation of it.

Comment: He told not go for it until he understands. Also, this might cause unwanted misunderstanding later with the VSCode behavior if you just set it and forget later what you did.