# VS Code task to open VS Code's simple browser with a url

Tags: visual-studio-code

I intend to write a task, that first runs a dev server command, and parallely opens VS code's Simple Browser (Command Pallette -> Simple Browser) to the url.

I dont need the task to dynamically get the url from the dev server.

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to make task to open the Simple Browser using [input variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables)

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "open simple browser",
      "command": "${input:openSimpleBrowser}"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "openSimpleBrowser",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "simpleBrowser.show",
      "args": ["https://xkcd.com"]
    }
  ]
}
```

One thing that I didn't find the documentation of is to find the name of the command. I found the name `simpleBrowser.show` by chance in VSCode itself. Apparently, you can get the name of each command in the command palette by:

1. search the command in the palette first
2. select the `Configure Binding` cog icon, which will take you to `Keyboard Shortcuts`
3. in the search bar, the name of the command will be written, e.g. `@command:simpleBrowser.show`
4. you'll only need the name after `:` for input variable

Comment: It will be good add `"problemMatcher": []` on the task to avoid the "Continue without scanning the task output" message.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519017/fix-continue-without-scanning-the-task-output-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: did you know if attaching the debugger to the Simple Browser is possible?