# How to use typescript in electron without having to compile?

Tags: typescript, electron

So it looks like with newer electrons you can just start it off in typescript right away with

> electron main.ts

1. Though you can't do `electron ./main` and you'd still need to require('./file.ts').
2. And I noticed that when I build it the .exe still complains that it needs a main.js file.

How can I solve these two issues without going with a compiler (just load typescript directly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron is not supposed to execute TypeScript code directly so you have to convert it to Javascript before to be able to use it in electron. By the way here a useful link to refer: https://www.electronjs.org/blog/typescript

Please refer also to this question: [How to add my own typescript classes in Electron project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498489/how-to-add-my-own-typescript-classes-in-electron-project)

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit of a let down really, if electron executes typescript seemlessly that would've been ideal.